# Lost bank information

Tags: united-states, banking, checking-account

I found an old bank check registry from my grandmother whom has passed away some years back, but the banks name is Akron national Bank and in the registry she had a balance. Is there anyway to track this down? If so our family would like to know

Comment: It might have been [escheated](https://www.sec.gov/answers/escheat.htm) by now

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This would be a long shot.

As per info on the net, [Akron National Bank](http://www.usbanklocations.com/akron-national-bank-12979.shtml) became inactive on 30-June-1979. This has moved through several acquisitions and is currently part of PNC.
As you can see it became part of [National City Bank](http://www.usbanklocations.com/national-city-bank-of-columbus-6561.shtml) and was acquired by National City Bank in 1998. National City Bank in 2009 was acquired by [PNC](http://www.usbanklocations.com/national-city-bank-6557.shtml).

As you can see if the account was indeed with Akron Nation Bank and no activity was done, it would have become dormant and funds transferred to Government.

What is more likely to have happened is your grandma may have automatically banked with National City Bank and forgot to destroy the old check Akron National Bank Check.

Your best bet is to check with PNC Bank. However given the merger history and the time duration, it would be very difficult for PNC to trace you account that is almost 35+ years old.

Comment: If the funds did escheat to the government, there may be a state "unclaimed property" registry where they could be recovered.

Comment: @BrenBarn government escheat invokes me the behaviour of a character from the LoTR movies... my... precious... but the picture of [vogons](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Vogon) saying that.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked it up on google, seems it has been acquired 3 times:

- Akron National Bank acquired by National City Bank of Columbus
- National City Bank of Columbus acquired by National City Bank
- National City Bank acquired by PNC Bank

> ```
> PNC Bank
> 222 Delaware Avenue
> Wilmington, DE 19899
> ```

Sources:

- http://www.usbanklocations.com/akron-national-bank-12979.shtml
- http://www.usbanklocations.com/pnc-bank.shtml